# How to develop a Flutter Plugin with Android Studio from git?

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to developing a Flutter Plugin so I decided to start with an existing Open source project I found on [Pub Dart Lang](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation) .

I use Android Studio and the [flutter location package](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation):

**Step 1:**

I used VCS > Check out from Version Control > Git
 to download the source code

**Step 2:**

I don't know what's step two. When I open the Java file, I see red lines everywhere

[image]

Android studio doesn't prompt me to do anything. What's the next step from there?